# Compressing Image Source path in Javascript

Tags: jquery, image, replace, attr, imagesource

I have a web app which replaces few img's with other img's.

For example: Image with path http://example.com/example/example/images/dir/1.gif is repalced with http://cdn.example.com/dir/1.gif.

To do this I use jQuery attr().

So my code looks something like this:

```
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/1.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/1.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/2.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/2.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/3.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/3.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/4.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/4.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/5.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/5.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/6.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/6.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/7.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/7.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/8.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/8.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/9.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/9.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/10.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/10.gif")
```

**So is there a way to compress this? So it's written in less characters?**

Note: On each line, images on both websites are the same. Example, 1.gif is replaced again with 1.gif but a different server. **So basically I want to replace the server**. When http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/ replace with http://cdn.example.com/dir/.

Thanks alot

Comment: If this is for performance reasons (bandwidth distribution), you should be doing this server-side.

Comment: +1 Phil, using a CDN to increase performance, but if you're doing this after page loads, i.e. the old images have already loaded and then you're doing the replaces, thats actually making performance worse

Comment: @Phil Images are retrieved from an API. So there is no way I can change that server-side unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as using a loop:

```
var i;
for ( i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
{
  $('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/'+i+'.gif"]').attr('src','http://cdn.example.com/dir/'+i+'.gif');
}
```

Or were you asking for a find and replace for all?

You could use the [attr starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('img[src^="http://www.example.com/"]').each(function(index,element){
  var $this, src, newSrc;
  $this = $(this);
  src = $this.attr('src');
  //do your replacement here
  newSrc = src.replace('www.example.com/dir/images/dir', 'cdn.example.com/dir');
  $this.attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

as Moin Zaman pointed out, attr can take a function as a parameter as well, which shortens this script to:

```
$('img[src^="http://www.example.com/"]').attr('src', function(index, src){
  return src.replace('www.example.com/dir/images/dir', 'cdn.example.com/dir');
});
```

Comment: Using a loop for this is overkill. the attribute selector is better but you dont need .each

Comment: @zzzzBov Thank you. The images names are random. Could be anything so I the first option wouldn't work. As for the second option can you explain me the img[src^=" ? Why do I have to include ^ ?

Comment: @jQuerybeast look at my answer below for the explanation of ^= and a better way to do what you're wanting

Comment: @zzzzBov is it possible I can change the extension aswell sir? Thanks in advance. From gif to png

Answer (score 1):

You need JavaScript's .replace() method with regular expressions to replace stuff.

in jQuery the attribute selector `^=` means look for attribute value that starts with.

Try this, I'm assuming its all images that start with 'www.example.com':

```
$('img[src^="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir"]').attr('src',
    function(i,src){ 
        return src.replace('example.com/dir/images/dir','cdn.example.com/dir') 
});
```

Comment: Down vote wasn't from me. Thanks for your answer. I will be checking it in a while.